# What is this watch expression in Angular.js Batarang?

Tags: performance, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do performance tuning on an Angular.js application using the Angular.js Batarang Chrome extension.  One of the extension's features is that it lists all the 'watch expressions' that Angular.js checks on each $digest, and shows how long they take to evaluate.  Most of the expressions look like:

```
'comment.commenter_profile_url'
'comment.commenter_name'
...
```

However, the most expensive watch expression on the page is apparently

```
"function (){f=i(c);var a,b;if(L(f))if(Xa(f))
{if(e!==h)e=h,x=e.length=0,g++;a=f.length;if(x!==a)g++,e.length=x=a;
for(b=0;b<a;b++)e[b]!==f[b]&&(g++,e[b]=f[b])}else{e!==n&&(e=n={},x=0,
g++);a=0;for(b in f)f.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(a++,e.hasOwnProperty(b)?
e[b]!==f[b]&&(g++,e[b]=f[b]):(x++,e[b]=f[b],g++));if(x>a)for(b in
g++,e)e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&!f.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(x--,delete e[b])}else
e!==f&&(e=f,g++);return g}"
```

(line breaks are mine).  What's going on here?  My best guess is that this is some sort of compiled filtered ng-repeat.  (If I'm correct, I'd really appreciate a summary of the sort of things Angular.js does -- if any -- to make ng-repeat and filters efficient.)

Comment: Why don't you try running your tests against the source for Angular, rather than the minified version?

Comment: Did you figure out what that watch did?